# return many arrays from json encoding

Tags: javascript, json

in my php code I want to return two arrays

```
$array_result[]+= $temp_score_by_weight;
$array_name[] .= $alter->name;
}
$return["result"] = $array_result;
$return["name"] = $array_name;

echo json_encode($return);
```

in javascript ajax function

```
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'result_calculation.php',
        success: function(data) {
            // call it again after one second
            alert(data);
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
```

the result of alert(data) was in this format below:

```
{"result":[1265,765],"name":["rmit","svu"]}
```

I want to take these information and put them in two separate javascript arrays ( array of result contains the two values, and the same array of names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify json format for your ajax call

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'result_calculation.php',
  success: function(data) {
    // call it again after one second
    alert(data["result"]);//first array
    alert(data["name"]);//second array
  },
  cache: false,
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = data.result;
var name = data.name;
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it doesn't work. it alert me undefined

Answer (score 0):

Just assign them to your arrays:

```
var result = data.result;
var name = data.name
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON requires that the outermost entity is a single object or array, so you do need to return an object from the server, if you want to send multiple arrays (and array of arrays would not be the best choice).

However, converting to two arrays is as simple as

```
var result = data.result;
var name   = data.name;
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it doesn't work. it alert me undefined

Comment: Can you provide the code that you actually tried? Since this code has no 'alert' in it, you must have added some of your own

Comment: data prints in the alert as a string this means he can't do data.something => json is not handled, must add dataType to the ajax call